# Get an int out of a Linq query instead of string

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-entities

I'm new to c#, Linq and .NET. I have some code that does a query to get the last record from a table in a database. The field that I'm trying to access is an int but when I try to print it I get `` System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1[System.Int32] ``.
Here's the code:

```
public void getLastProgNumber() 
        {
            using (var db = new IntranetEntities())
            {
                var value = (db.table.OrderByDescending(ai => ai.NumProgHWSW).GroupBy(a => a.NumProgHWSW).Select(g => Convert.ToInt32(g.FirstOrDefault())));
                MessageBox.Show(value.ToString());
            }            
        }
```

I need to convert it to an int type and return it if possible, thank you. (Right now I'm using `void` because I'm trying to get the right result before returning it)

Comment: Why you need to do group by? You just do `var val = (db.table.OrderByDescending(ai => ai.NumProgHWSW).FirstOrDefault();` and then `MessageBox.Show(val.NumProgHWSW);`

Comment: Do you need to select the `NumProgHWSW` column? or do you have another column you wish to select.

Comment: Yes I need to select that specific column. @ChetanRanpariya your solution works but how can I assign that value to an int variable now to return it?

Comment: What are you trying to do? This looks like a `MAX(NumProgHWSW)` query.  If `NumProgHWSW` is a string, the query will fail simply because the values will be ordered alphabetically

Comment: @Otori why is a number stored as a text to begin with? `"2"` will always come before `"1000"`. In any case, instead of `Order.First` just use `Max()` or `Min()`, ie `db.Table.Max(ai=>ai.NumProgHWSH)`

Comment: You should do `var val = (db.table.OrderByDescending(ai => ai.NumProgHWSW).FirstOrDefault().NumProgHWSW;` but this will throw error if the table is empty.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'm doing this because some values in the column are 0 or NULL.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya this isn't a problem since it will never be empty. Once again it works. Post it as answer and I'll mark it as correct

Comment: @Otori in that case store `0` or `NULL`, don't turn the field into a string. `MAX` doesn't even care about 0s and `NULL` won't be returned if there are other values. Even if there's no other page number you can use `?? ` to replace the null with whatever value you want

Comment: @Otori how would you write the *same* query in SQL? LINQ to EF isn't magic, it generates SQL. If you want the largest `NumProgHWSW` you'd write `SELECT MAX(NumProgHWSW) from Table`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the last record from the database table, there are multiple ways. But doing GroupBy is certainly not one of them.

You can order the rows by doing OrderByDescending so that row with the maximum value of that column positioned at the first and then you can do `FirstOrDefault`.

```
var val = db.table.OrderByDescending(ai => ai.NumProgHWSW).FirstOrDefault();
// val is the row with maximum value of NumProgHWSW.
// you can display the value of NumProgHWSW in messagebox by doing following.
MessageBox.Show(val.NumProgHWSW);
```

If you want to get the Maximum value of `NumProgHWSW` in a variable directly from the LINQ query. you can do this by

```
var val = db.table.OrderByDescending(ai => ai.NumProgHWSW).FirstOrDefault().NumProgHWSW;
MessageBox.Show(val);
```

You can also use `Max` LINQ method to get the maximum value without doing OrderByDescending.

```
var val = db.table.Max(ai => ai.NumProgHWSW);
MessageBox.Show(val);
```

Using `Max` is a better approach then above two as it does not order the table rows before data retrieval and that way it works faster when the table has large number of rows.